# Need to copy lines from one text to another based on a key item

Tags: c#

I am trying to copy lines from one text file to another which contains a key item in it (For example: "2011"). The following are the lines that are present in my source text.

> PensonReport: 1/11/2010 11:14:21 AM, Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
>   Parameter name: length, Sub ProcessDateHeader_BeforePrint, ReportRequestID: 24614361, DALBATCHDEV01
>
> ReportRequest: 8/16/2011 10:02:26 AM, Procedure or function 'prcEXT602' expects parameter '@CorrespondentOfficeID', which was not supplied., Sub ExecuteStoredProc, ReportRequestID: 49474706, DALBATCHDEV01

The problem with my code is that it is not able to identify the EOL and is printing the whole of it.
Note: each new line starts from string ReportRequest.
How do I do this?

Comment: How you try to "identify the EOL"? Are you using `File.ReadAllLines` method? Please post some code..

Answer (score 2):

You will want to start with StreamReader, and have it open your first file.

Then use a StreamWriter to write the info out.

Next couple a while loop together with the streamwriter to look at each line and then you should be able to use an.

My C# syntax may be off leave a comment if I have something really off please.

```
string line;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("newfile.txt"))
//Use a while loop that reads each line until there are none left
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null
{
         line = reader.ReadLine();
         if (line.contains("your string here"))
         then writer.WriteLine();
}
```

EDIT: Added code to better answer question

```
        string line;
        String Report = "ReportRequest";
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))          
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("newfile.txt"))


            while (reader.ReadLine() != null)                   
            {
                if (reader.ReadLine().StartsWith(Report))
                {
                    //writes/starts a new line beginning with ReportRequest
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }
                else {
                    //appends info to same line (beginning with a space)
                    writer.Write(" " + line);
                }                       
                }
```

Comment: I have done exactly the same thing. But my problem is that ,it has to pick up the whole line Starting from ReportRequest till another ReportRequest is reached. Because string ReportRequest is the starting point of each new line.Hope I have not confused you.:P

Comment: @Yashaswini You said each of the blocks in your question are lines? I must be a little confused. So each actualy line does not start with ReportRequest? So actually every 4 or 5 lines is one line?

Comment: Also there may be a if (line.startswith("Report")) method. Try that?

Comment: Yeah they all are part of same line.I am doing a log check and hence those 3-4 lines are part of single information.I hope you got it..

Comment: @Yashaswini I added something a lil better that shoudl work. It reads each line if the line doesnt start with what you want it adds that line to the same line.

Answer (score 0):

If each line starts with "ReportRequest" use

```
string[] splits = mybigstring.Split("ReportRequest");
```

If this is what you're asking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Maeby try use something like this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("oldFile.txt")
    .Where(s => s.Contains("your_text")).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines("newFile", lines);
```